# How to style v-btn-toggle to skip theme--light

Tags: css, vue.js

I have button group which seems to be styled by vue with theme-light and buttons are much lighter before its clicked. How to skip the light theme and keep colors defined in css file?  I want to have the buttons in color of #3399ff even they are not selected.

```
<v-flex xs12 md12 class="my-3" flat>
    <v-btn-toggle flat>
        <v-btn outline class="left primary groupSearchType">
            button 1
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn outline class="pa-0 primary groupSearchType">
            button 2
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn outline class="right groupSearchType">
            button 3
        </v-btn>
    </v-btn-toggle>
</v-flex>
```

Following css doesnt work for me

```
   button.groupSearchType {
        border-color: #3399ff !important;
        height: 20px !important;
        font-size: 4px !important;   
        font-weight: bolder !important;
        font-style: normal !important;
        color: #3399ff !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `outline` attribute at each `v-btn` tag? and defining `background-color: #3399ff !important;` in your css. And if you want you can also remove the `primary` class from each `v-btn` tag.

```
<v-flex xs12 md12 class="my-3" flat>
  <v-btn-toggle flat>
      <v-btn class="left groupSearchType">
          button 1
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn class="pa-0 groupSearchType">
          button 2
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn class="right groupSearchType">
          button 3
      </v-btn>
  </v-btn-toggle>
</v-flex>
```

Comment: I just tried css styles with !important and it works, but I'm not sure if this is correct practice to make all deklarations with !important.